# Getting an internet connection to get drivers for wlan

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, internet, iphone

My situation is that my wlan is broken. I have this other one i want to use. My pc at the moment has **no internet connection** which makes this awkward. Basically i can use:

`Laptop` with an ethernet connection (running ubuntu try it instance at the moment, normally windows 7)

`Iphone`

Both ways are really easy to connect, except you need a prior connection.

I have already tried connecting an ethernet cable to pc - laptop and changing both `ipv4` settings to shared computers. Doesnt work. I just need a way to gain temporarily access to internet on my pc to put some commands in the terminal, for either the iphone or wlan.

Comment: IPv6 has fully automatic link-local address configuration, so an IP connection should work out of the box. What kind of services do you actually want to share between the two machines? It's still rather unclear to me, what you're asking. If you have issue with Wifi configuration on Ubuntu, please run the [diagnostic script](/q/425155) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: I want internet. Wifi. Whatever. Just something so i can retrieve packages and updates. Well, it isnt working out the box. I tried without configuring and it just kept looping that it was trying to connect but never got a connection. How am i meant to run that script if i dont have the connection, wtf.

Comment: You could use tethering, use your phone as an access point

Answer (score 2):

So basically your internal WiFi card is broken, and you have no Ethernet cable and the new WiFi dongle you bought needs drivers downloaded from the Internet, but your crappy iPhone doesn't have an SD card so files downloaded cannot be easily transferred...

The only solution I see is downloading the drivers on the iPhone and sending it through BlueTooth to the PC...

Otherwise you'll still have to go out and buy a network cable and hook up the laptop to the router directly...  :-(

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.